# Invalid username and password , Login

Tags: cakephp

I'm using Cakephp version 2.5.4

the problem is I can't login , $this->Auth->login() returns false everytime !!

the same result with or without hashing the password , what could be wrong ? 
spent a whole day checking the code , but no way ..

I'll appreciate it if you have time to check the code here : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2e0c6ab6b3b9a8604893

everything included : User.php , UsersController.php , login.ctp , register.ctp

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think `$this->data` isn't available in cakephp 2.x. You should change `$this->data` to `$this->request->data` and all fields will be available to Auth.

What class and hashType you are using in AppController? You need to use the same hashType in AppController and in the Model.

Example,
App Controller:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => array(
                    'className' => 'Simple',
                    'hashType' => 'sha256'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Model:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher(array('hashType' => 'sha256'));
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: He is right! Use $this->data in Model and $this->request->data in controller!

function login() {
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {                   
  if($this->Auth->login()) {   
   return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); 
 }
  $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Username or Password please try again');
 }
}

Comment: `Controller::$data` is still available ([**via magic properties**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.4/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L395)) for backwards compatibility purposes.

Answer (score 1):

ok in your AppController include this function:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
   Security::setHash('sha1');

}
```

you are saying that your encription is sha1

now in your database in your field 'password' should be VARCHAR (30) not more than 30 characters.

And I'm not shure about this line in register.ctp, and there is a comma more after of true this is a wrong

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User',array('type' => 'file','novalidate' => true,));?>
```

Why is a file? I thing that just should be this

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
```

and novalidate could be initialized in the database with true, then only upgrade to new value

Ok.
I told you what you have to add in AppController now add this go into UserController. That's what happens when you look at a form to store user information many times to use sha1 Encryption Key and this is the encryption with the we store in the database at the time of signup. But often it is not the same when logging in may be sending this with another type of encryption and what happens is that when validating data for authentication compare a (sha1 (password registration) == other encryption (login password)) is because specific beforeFilter in the Encryption Key.

added this and change in User controller:

```
  public function beforeFilter() {
         parent::beforeFilter();
  }
  public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                if($this->Auth->user('activated')==1){
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Bienvenido, '. $this->Auth->user('username')));
                     return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Email is not verified. Please verify and try again.'));
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
                }
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid Username or Password please try again'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but sha1 is not related to the password it hashes the token that i'm sending in the activation link .
the type of the form is file because i had an avatar uploading field , but not anymore and forgot to remove it , anyway still getting invalid username and password , even with those changes

Comment: edit my answer, I thought it had something to do with the hash of the password.

Comment: Try to move this condition (if ($results['User']['activated']==1)) to Auth Configure Scope: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers
Debug your passwords in order to see if hashed password from the form == hashed password from your database http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords
Use the same hashType!

Comment: debugging the password shows **** so I can't be sure , I'm using debugger::dump()

Comment: The problem was with this line:  $this->User->data = $this->data;

Comment: Ho Gob i don't see that :) ok now there isn't problem, but with my answer you should solve the problem too.

Comment: thanks , i will correct them , but can't do that before tomorrow morning unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It's actually happening because you may have not use password hash.You can add bellow code in your user model.

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

Just add this code in your model.Then made a user again.If you already add this code in your model then see the database.Is it saving hashing password? If yes then this error can happen for another reason that is if you change your security salt after make user.You can solve this problem by make a new user.Now question how you will make a user?

In your appController add

`$this->Auth->allow();`

in your beforeFilter() method.Then go again in your browser and you can access to make a new user.After make user try again for login.I think it will work.